# Using enum values in combination with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am already familiar with SFINAE and how it can be used to enable specific templates based on the passed type (by using std::enable_if). However I have recently started working on a project where I'd like to do the following: create a class specialization based on the provided enum VALUE while using SFINAE. Now, I know that it's possible to make specializations based on an enum value considering I've done this before (like so):

```cpp
enum Specifier
{
   One,
   Two,
   Three
}

template <Specifier>
class Foo
{
public:
   void Bar();
}

template<>
void Foo<Specifier::One>::Bar()
{
}
```

However now I'd like to use SFINAE to use a specific specialization of `Bar()` for multiple enum values. Something like this:

```cpp
template <Specifier Type>
class Foo
{
public:
   template <typename std::enable_if<Type == Specifier::Two || Type == Specifier::One, void>::type> 
   void Bar();

   template <typename std::enable_if<Type == Specifier::Three, void>::type> 
   void Bar();
}
```

Any idea if this is possible, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does this code compile? what the `Bar()` function return?

Comment: @Harry I've edited my post to add a return type to bar. I didn't originally include it considering that I didn't think it would be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### C++17: constexpr if

From C++17 and onwards, you could use a single member function overload (instead of several overloads present or not present via SFINAE) whose body leverages constexpr if:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Specifier { One, Two, Three };

template <Specifier S> class Foo {
public:
  static constexpr int bar() {
    if constexpr ((S == Specifier::One) || (S == Specifier::Two)) {
      return 12;
    } else if constexpr (S == Specifier::Three) {
      return 3;
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << Foo<Specifier::One>::bar() << "\n" // 12
            << Foo<Specifier::Two>::bar() << "\n" // 12
            << Foo<Specifier::Three>::bar();      // 3
}
```

---

#### C++11: SFINAE and `std::enable_if`(`_t`) (C++14)

You can likewise use SFINAE with the requirement that your non-template member functions need to be made member function templates with a dummy template parameter, as SFINAE needs to be applied to a *dependent name* in each function declaration, and a class template (type or non-type) parameter is naturally not a dependent name in the declaration of a *non-template* member function:

```
template <Specifier S> class Foo {
public:
  template <Specifier S_ = S,
            std::enable_if_t<(S_ == Specifier::One) || (S_ == Specifier::Two)>
                * = nullptr>
  static constexpr int bar() {
    return 12;
  }

  template <Specifier S_ = S,
            std::enable_if_t<(S_ == Specifier::Three)> * = nullptr>
  static constexpr int bar() {
    return 3;
  }
};
```

Note that the example above uses the helper alias template `std::enable_if_t` that was introduced in C++14. If you are using C++11, you will need to use `typename std::enable_if<..>::type` instead.

Moreover note that as we have to templetize the member functions an abusive user could choose to override the default template argument for the (dummy) non-type template parameter `S_`:

```
Foo<Specifier::One>::bar<Specifier::Three>();  // 3
```

So we may want to add an additional AND condition to the `std::enable_if_t` predicate for each overload, namely `(S_ == S) && (... predicate as above)`. As we shall see in the section that follows, this is no longer an issue in C++20, as we can avoid making non-template member functions into templates solely for applying SFINAE.

***Alternative using specializations rather than overloading***

As I've also shown in [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64912160/4573247) to a follow up question to this question, you may also apply SFINAE in the template argument list (to the class template being partially specialized) of a specialization:

```
template <Specifier, typename = void> struct Foo {
  static constexpr int bar() { return 1; }  // default
};

template <Specifier S>
struct Foo<S,
           std::enable_if_t<(S == Specifier::One) || (S == Specifier::Two)>> {
  static constexpr int bar() { return 12; }
};
```

---

#### C++20: non-template member functions of class templates may use *requires-clause*:s

As of C++20, you can overload and constrain a non-template member function of a class template using a trailing *requires-clause* with mutual exclusive constraints for each overloaded:

```
template <Specifier S> class Foo {
public:
  static constexpr int bar() requires((S == Specifier::One) ||
                                      (S == Specifier::Two)) {
    return 12;
  }

  static constexpr int bar() requires(S == Specifier::Three) { return 3; }
};
```