# why template parameter which is explicitely given can not be "deduced"

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

Coming from that question:
[Using enum values in combination with SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910940/using-enum-values-in-combination-with-sfinae)

I tried to implement:

```
enum Specifier
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
};

template <Specifier, typename UNUSED=void>
struct Foo 
{
        void Bar(){ std::cout << "Bar default" << std::endl;}
};

template <Specifier s , typename std::enable_if<s == Specifier::Two || s == Specifier::One, int>::type>
struct Foo<s>
{
    void Bar(){ std::cout << "Bar Two" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
   Foo< One >().Bar();
   Foo< Two >().Bar();
}
```

Fails with:

```
> main.cpp:130:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
  130 | struct Foo<s>
      |        ^~~~~~
   main.cpp:130:8: note:         '<anonymous>'
```

How to fix that super simple example? I like SFINAE :-)

Comment: your code looks different from the one in the accepted answer on the question you link

Comment: @idclev463035818: Yes, because it is MY try to solve it. And I can't catch the point why!

Comment: maybe clarify that in the question. I now understand that this is an attempt to answer that question, not an attempt to apply the answer, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `enable_if` in `Foo`'s template argument list:

```
template <Specifier s>
struct Foo<s, typename std::enable_if<s == Specifier::Two || s == Specifier::One, void>::type>
//                                           same as the default type used before ^^^^
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8hKM67).

Comment: @dfrib Sure, but I feel it's important to highlight that it has to be the same as the deafult argument in the first definition of `Foo`, otherwise it's not going to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As the error tells us, template arguments are not deducible in partial specialization. In your example you have tried to place the SFINAE construct in the template *parameter* list of the specialization, but you need to move it to the template *argument* list (of the class being specialized) of the specialization declaration.

```
template <Specifier S>
struct Foo<S, std::enable_if_t<(S == Specifier::Two) || (S == Specifier::One)>>
```

Applied to your example (cleaned up a bit):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Specifier {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
};

template <Specifier, typename = void>
struct Foo {
    static void bar() { std::cout << "bar default\n"; }
};

template <Specifier S>
struct Foo<S, std::enable_if_t<(S == Specifier::Two) || (S == Specifier::One)>> {
    static void bar() { std::cout << "bar One or Two\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Foo<Specifier::One>::bar();    // bar One or Two
    Foo<Specifier::Two>::bar();    // bar One or Two
    Foo<Specifier::Three>::bar();  // bar default
}
```

Note that you needn't name the non-used type template parameter in the primary template of the class template `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple fact that template-arguments in template specializations are not deduceable.

Not that you need it.

Just change the template speialization:

```
template <Specifier s>
struct Foo<s, std::enable_if_t<s == Specifier::Two || s == Specifier::One, int>>
```

Though of course the result of `std::enable_if_t` here being `int` instead of `void` makes it somewhat useless.

Also, as others commented, using concepts or at least `requires` instead of the extra template-argument of the primary template is much more convenient.

Comment: Compiles, but did not select the right specialization when calling from the given main. It always prints "Bar default"

Comment: I think I added an explanantion for that just before your comment, and added more to that just after...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/86MbfY doesnt work. change the `int` to `void`

Comment: @JHBonarius: yep, that was the problem :-) Thanks

Comment: That "concepts" is the better way and easier to read is quite clear, but I simply want some "old SFINAE pain" :-) only for my personal education...